# Can we have static variable for initilizing driver in selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

We have a static variable to initialize driver in Selenium WebDriver.

`public static WebDriver driver;`

This variable is declared in a class (DriverInit) and initialized in "@BeforeClass" of various Test Plans(Test Classes). The initialized variable (driver) will be used across the project in various re-usable functions and @test methods. Driver will be closed/quit at the @QAfterClass

This works fine with non-paralled execution of scripts. Does having a static variable to initialize the driver affect parallel execution by any means?

Eg :

```
public class DriverInit { (using remote webdriver, browser name will be read from XML)
  public static WebDriver driver;    
  public DriverInit() {
    switch (browser) {
    case "IE" : driver = ....
    case "Firefox" : driver = ....
    }
  }
}

public class TestClass {
  @BeforeClass
  public void BeforeClass() {
   DriverInit driver = new DriverInit();
  }

  @Test
  public void Test1() {
   DriverInit.driver.findElementBy();
   Reusable.func1();
  }
}

Public class Reusable {

  public WebElement r1;
  public Reusable() {
    r1 = DriverInit.driver.findElementBy(..);
  }
  public void func1() {
     r1.findElementBy(..);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not correct to use the static for driver instance. 
It's better to create get_method to return the driver to another class.

```
public class DriverInit { (using remote webdriver, browser name will be read from XML)
private WebDriver driver;

public WebDriver getDriver() {
switch (browser) {
case "IE" : driver = ....
case "Firefox" : driver = ....
return driver;
}
}

public class TestClass {
private Webdriver driver;
@BeforeClass
public void BeforeClass() {
DriverInit driveInit= new DriverInit();
driver=driveInit.getDriver();
}

@Test
public void Test1() {
Reusable reusable = new Reusable();
reusable.func1Click(driver);
}
}

public class Reusable {

public void func1Click(WebDriver driver) {
driver.findElementBy(..).click();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you stated, you can use a static driver, but, yes, you are risking a shared memory issue if you do any parallelization directly at the test code level.

I've avoided using a static driver for just this reason, it's bad design for a test suite that may grow into parallelization. Running a single process launching tests on multiple servers in a selenium grid would not work.

The way I've designed around this situation is to pass the driver (created in the @Before) to each page object when I initialize them.

If the suite WILL NOT grow, you can still use the static driver, and launch multiple tests as separate jobs (i.e. separate Jenkins jobs, or separate runs from the command line, etc)

Comment: To avoid parallel execution problem, Can static driver instance be used in Thread safe way?

Answer (score 1):

Use Singleton class in which you define your webDriver,
then use the same instance in your other classes

Answer (score 0):

When you define your field as `static` then every thread has access to it and every thread can modify that memory space. That is is why I have doubts about possibility to use webdriver instance defined as `static`. But you can consider using [Selenium Grid](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) in order to run multiple tests across different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I have used static Webdriver object. I used it in everypart of test (@Before, @Test, @After also while element locatining / pageobject modelling ).I checked JVM. Performance looks quite well. Because you can kill, destroy this object after every test case.

But when parallel test in question. If you are using testNg you can manage it with xml file.
But if you are using Junit (junit-platform.properties file or @Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)) I have met some problems as mensioned above.
Java user must be away from static.

To solve this problem you need static and ThreadLocal instances..

```
private final static ThreadLocal<DriverFactorySingleton> driverFactorySingleton = new ThreadLocal<>();
private final static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<>();
```